# не могу сделать авторизацию с яндекс диском

Tags: php, curl

есть код пишет не авторизован

```json
{"message":"Не авторизован.","description":"Unauthorized","error":"UnauthorizedError"}
```

делаю все следующим образом через `curl`:

```php
$curl = curl_init();
$authorization = "Authorization: Bearer AQAAAAAaQCuCAAQq1jq7m_Тwq0HJnUBAhzdZINg"; // не могу понять куда эту перемнную  подстваить 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://cloud-api.yandex.net:443/v1/disk");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $result;
```

или так но пишет тоже самое:

```php
$curl = curl_init(); curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://cloud-api.yandex.net:443/v1/disk?access_token=AQAAAAAaQCuCAAQq1jq7m_Тwq0HJnUBAhzdZINg");добавляю токе curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); $result = curl_exec($curl);//выполняется сам курл curl_close($curl); print $result;
```

Answer (score 1):

сделал нужно использовать массив

```html
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$curl = curl_init();
$headers = array(
    'Content-type: application/xml',
    'Authorization: AQAAAAAaQCuCAAQq1jq7m_Тwq0HJnUBAhzdZINg',
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://cloud-api.yandex.net:443/v1/disk");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $result;
```

нужно просто записать в массив

```html
$headers = array(
    'Content-type: application/xml',
    'Authorization: AQAAAAAaQCuCAAQq1jq7m_Тwq0HJnUBAhzdZINg',
)
```